# Draw a Texture to fit a rectangle

Tags: c#, xna, textures, monogame

I would like to draw a texture in a rectangle that is smaller than the texture, normally the texture will be scaled to fill the rectangle, which results in a squished image. I want to draw it to fit.

For example, if the green stuff is the Texture, I would like to draw only the stuff in the red rectangle.

[image]

I already tried to get the color data from the base texture and create a new one, filled with the part from the base.

```
Color[] colorData = new Color[progressRectangle.Width * progressRectangle.Height];
Color[] sourceColorData = new Color[t2dBack.Width * t2dBack.Height];
t2dBack.GetData(sourceColorData);
for (int x = 0; x < progressRectangle.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < progressRectangle.Height; y++)
    {
        colorData[x + progressRectangle.Width * y] = sourceColorData[x + t2dBack.Width * y];
    }
}

t2dBackDraw.SetData(colorData);
```

but that just results in gibberish.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily draw part of a texture with a simple Spritebatch.Draw command.  Consider the following:

```
// width and height of your red rectangle
int width = 100;
int height = 100;

// start x and y position, in texture coordinates
int x = 120;
int y = 0;

// rectangles for our draw call
Rectangle destinationRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

spriteBatch.Draw(mainTexture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White);
```

This draw call, will draw the sourceRectangle portion of the texture onto the screen at the desired location.

See more here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433987.aspx

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/RG0BS1U.gif